# Port Chrome Extension to Firefox, Safari, IE

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome-extension, safari

I would like to start making a cross-browser extension. I understand that all APIs and structures are different per browser, but is there any universal practice to follow?

*I have searched over Stackoverflow and none of questions provide a universal solution to produce cross-browser extensions.*

Comment: Because there is no universal solution, perhaps? Also, it is probably off-topic here as _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource"_

Comment: Ok, you are right. I close it then.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, The best solution is to use adapters class that will call browser api. After you can have a code that will work on every browser by using the right adapter.

For example in the background script you don't have setTimeout/setInterval for firefox but you have it for chrome. You can have a code like this

**Core.js**

```
this._browserAdapter.setTimeout(function(){...}, 1000);
```

**ChromeAdapter.js**

```
setTimeout: function (callback, time) {
        return setTimeout(callback, time);
}
```

**FirefoxAdapter.js**

```
setTimeout: function(callback, time) {

        var {setTimeout} = require("sdk/timers");
        return setTimeout(callback, time);
},
```

You can do everything using this way, so you will be able to have more than 90% of your code in common.

---

**Edit**

It will work for firefox and safari. For IE it's completely different, but with the new microsoft EDGE I think it will be possible to have something like this. Wait and see !

Comment: This is the same solution I came up with here. It's a bit tricky to make sure you get everything, but we're using a UMD JS (https://github.com/umdjs/umd) module format to structure the code. We use RequireJS (http://requirejs.org) to load modules in Chrome while Firefox extensions use Mozilla's Common JS implementation.